# Kotlin Shared Flow with uncertain amount of replay value

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-sharedflow

I have a shared flow and a collector that will attach to it and collect a couple of seconds after the flow will emit values.
I need the collector to be able to get values emitted before it had a chance to attach.
I know Shared Flow has "replay" that you can set for this scenario, but what if I dont know how many values I will miss, should I just set replay = Int.MAX_VALUE and leave it like that or is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: You can set reasonable yet large bufferSize for replayed values. However, if you want to get all emissions why won't you use a cold flow or store values somewhere?

Comment: Exactly, if you always want all previously emitted values Flow is not the right data type. Just use a List.